# Problemas para acceder a un atributo privado

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, objeto, programacion-asincrona

```
from  figura_geometrica import FiguraGeometrica
from  color import Color

class Cuadrado(FiguraGeometrica, Color):

    def __init__(self, lado,color):

        FiguraGeometrica.__init__(self, lado, lado)
        Color.__init__(self, color)

    def area(self):
        return self.__ancho * self.__alto
```

Obtengo la siguiente excepción:

> AttributeError: 'Cuadrado' object has no attribute '_Cuadrado__ancho'

Answer (score 1):

Primero señalar que eso no es un atributo privado, **los atributos/métodos privados no existen en Python**, sin más, no al menos con el mismo concepto de "privado" que hay en lenguajes como C++ o Java.

A ese mecanismo se le conoce como "name mangling" (nombre con doble subrayado inicial sin doble subrayado final) y está pensado para **evitar colisiones de nombres entre clases**, especialmente para evitar sobrescrituras no deseadas en subclases de dicho atributo/método. En ningún momento se pensó para hacer privado un atributo, de hecho podemos acceder a él si queremos sin problemas si sabemos cómo. Es un error muy común en Python que viene de un malentendido histórico que no viene al caso.

El mangling se lleva acabo durante la generación del bytecode y depende de dónde es definido el método o atributo solamente, no desde dónde es llamado. Cuando el intérprete se encuentra con el atributo `self.__alto` en `FiguraGeometrica` a la hora de generar el bytecode de la clase lo renombra a `self._FiguraGeometrica__alto`, es decir, pasa de:

```
<instancia>.__alto
```

a:

```
<instancia>._FiguraGeometrica__alto
```

La idea es que si alguien define `alto` o `ancho` en una subclase no solape los atributos del padre. De hecho, la idea sería que la clase hija directamente  no use dichos atributos. Además evitaría el solapamiento entre atributos de clases en herencia múltiple, si tu clase `Color` tuviera esos mismos atributos por ejemplo, sin el name mangling colisionarían.

Por lo tanto, para acceder al atributo desde la clase hija deberías hacer:

```
def area(self):
    return self._FiguraGeometrica__ancho * self._FiguraGeometrica__alto
```

Por convención se usa un simple subrayado (`self._ancho`) para denotar que un atributo/método debe considerarse "privado", el desarrollador queda avisado, si quiere acceder a él puede, el lenguaje no lo impide, se supone que sabe lo que hace. El uso del name mangling para intentar hacer privado un atributo (como se entiende en C++ por ejemplo), además de imposible (como hemos visto basta con referenciarlo con el nombre correcto para acceder a él) es incorrecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaracion