# Organizar Listas de objetos en Python (Atributos Privados)

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente problema en Python. Necesito ordenar listas de Objetos de acuerdo a la edad, pero al ser los atributos privados, no me permite acceder a ellos mediante el attrgetter (Que es la única solucion que he encontrado). Si le saco los __ a los atributos funciona correctamente, pero me obligan a que los atributos sean privados. ¿Como puedo hacer para que me ordene los objetos con los atributos privados?

```
def __init__(self,nombre,edad,altura):
    self.__nombre= nombre
    self.__edad= edad
    self.__altura= altura

def mostrar(self):
    print (self.__nombre,self.__edad,self.__altura) 

ListaPersona= []

per1= Persona('Luciano',22,188)
per2= Persona('Matias',24,180)
per3= Persona('Gonzalo',23,189)
per4= Persona('Mario',20,178)

ListaPersona.append(per1)
ListaPersona.append(per2)
ListaPersona.append(per3)
ListaPersona.append(per4)

for i in range(4):
    ListaPersona[i].mostrar()

NuevaLista = sorted(ListaPersona, key=attrgetter('__edad'))

for i in range(4):
    NuevaLista[i].mostrar()
```

Comment: Resultaría conveniente seguir la guía de estilos de código PEP 8 de Python a la hora de redactar el código. En el caso de los nombres de las variables, deben ir en minúscula y si están formadas por más de una palabra, se deben separar por el carácter '_'. Extraído de la guía (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): 
"Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability. Variable names follow the same convention as function names."
Así, por ejemplo, 'ListaPersona' quedaría como 'lista_persona' o incluso, 'personas'.

Comment: Hola Grommy! Muchas gracias por aportar esa información. Empezaré a utilizarlo de ahora en más. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el mismo que el planteado en esta otra pregunta:

- [Problemas para acceder a un atributo privado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/346373/15089)

No son atributos privados, a eso se le conoce como name mangling, puedes por tanto acceder al atributo así:

```
NuevaLista = sorted(ListaPersona, key=attrgetter('_Persona__edad'))
```

Esto mismo es la prueba de que no existen los atributos privados en Python, ¡estamos accediendo a él desde fuera de la clase! Si fueran privados esto debería ser imposible.

No obstante, en tu caso particular tienes otras posibilidades (independientemente de que uses name mangling o sigas las convenciones de `_atributo_privado`).

Si tu idea es que se considere un objeto Persona mayor menor o igual dependiendo de la edad puedes implementar los métodos necesarios en la clase (ver el [modelo de datos de Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__)) para que `sorted` o los operadores de comparación sepan como ordenar los objetos:

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad, altura):
        self.__nombre= nombre
        self.__edad= edad
        self.__altura= altura

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.__nombre} {self.__edad} {self.__altura}"

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.__edad < other.__edad

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.__edad > other.__edad

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__edad == other.__edad

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.edad <= other.__edad

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.__edad >= other.__edad

lista_personas = []

per1 = Persona('Luciano', 22, 188)
per2 = Persona('Matias', 24, 180)
per3 = Persona('Gonzalo', 23, 189)
per4 = Persona('Mario', 20, 178)

lista_personas.append(per1)
lista_personas.append(per2)
lista_personas.append(per3)
lista_personas.append(per4)

for persona in lista_personas:
    print(persona)

nueva_lista_personas = sorted(lista_personas)

print("Lista ordenada")
for persona in nueva_lista_personas:
    print(persona)
```

Otra posibilidad, si te obligan a usar name mangling sería un enfoque similar a lo que haríamos en otros lenguajes, usar setters y getters, que en el caso de Python lo más cercano son las propiedades:

```
from operator import attrgetter


class Persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad, altura):
        self.__nombre= nombre
        self.__edad= edad
        self.__altura= altura

    @property
    def nombre(self):
        return self.__nombre

    @property
    def edad(self):
        return self.__edad

    @property
    def altura(self):
        return self.__altura

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.__nombre} {self.__edad} {self.__altura}"



lista_personas = []

per1 = Persona('Luciano', 22, 188)
per2 = Persona('Matias', 24, 180)
per3 = Persona('Gonzalo', 23, 189)
per4 = Persona('Mario', 20, 178)

lista_personas.append(per1)
lista_personas.append(per2)
lista_personas.append(per3)
lista_personas.append(per4)

for persona in lista_personas:
    print(persona)

nueva_lista_personas = sorted(lista_personas, key=attrgetter("edad"))

for persona in nueva_lista_personas:
    print(persona)
```

No uses `for i in range()` para solo obtener los item de una lista, es ineficiente y poco pitónico, usa un `for in` sobre ella directamente.

Comment: Hola FJSevilla, muchisimas gracias por tu explicación. Me quedo muy claro todo.

Comment: De nada, por cierto, bienvenido a [es.so]. Un saludo.