# ¿Por qué no existe una variable en la clase hija en Python?

Tags: python, herencia, encapsulamiento

Resulta que estoy aprendiendo sobre POO en general, y me ha dado por comenzar con python.

Viendo un video explicativo de clases y tal, he estado haciendo pruebas con herencias, y resulta que al tener encapsuladas las variables, en la clase heredada, no coge las variables que debe coger de su herencia. Os pongo el código y el error.

```
class Personaje():

    def __init__(self,nombre,fuerza,inteligencia,fe,defensa):
        self.__nombre=nombre
        self.__fuerza=fuerza
        self.__inteligencia=inteligencia
        self.__fe=fe
        self.__defensa=defensa
        self.__vida=100
    
    def atributos(self):
        print("Nombre:",self.__nombre)
        print("Fuerza:",self.__fuerza)
        print("Inteligencia:",self.__inteligencia)
        print("Fe:",self.__fe)
        print("Vida:",self.__vida)

    def esta_vivo(self):
        return self.__vida >0
    
    def atacar(self,enemigo):
        daño=self.daño(enemigo)
        enemigo.__vida=enemigo.__vida-daño
        print(self.__nombre,"Ha causado",daño,"puntos de daño a",enemigo.__nombre)
        print("La vida de {a} es actualmente: {b}".format(a=enemigo.__nombre,b=enemigo.__vida))

    def daño(self,enemigo):
        return self.__fuerza-enemigo.__defensa

    def morir(self):
        self.__vida=0
        print(self.__nombre,"Ha muerto")
    
    def get_fuerza(self):
        print(self.__fuerza)
    
class Guerrero(Personaje):

    def __init__(self,nombre,fuerza,inteligencia,fe,defensa,espada):
        super().__init__(nombre,fuerza,inteligencia,fe,defensa)
        self.espada=espada

    def daño(self,enemigo):
        return self.__fuerza*self.espada - enemigo.defensa
    
    
mi_personaje=Guerrero("Edward",25,4,10,9,4)
enemigo=Personaje("John",20,4,15,10)
mi_personaje.atributos()
mi_personaje.atacar(enemigo)
mi_personaje.get_fuerza()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es como si la heredada no tuviese acceso a su propia variable fuerza (pasa con todas las demás).

Comment: No pongas imágenes, copia el código tal cual y para ponerlo en formato código, selecciónalo todo y pulsa Ctrl + K. Mira [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar tu pregunta

Comment: Entonces no es una duda, es un error. Por cierto, en Python existe un [decorador](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6618002/13419694) más útil que getters y setters.

Comment: @DanielSánchez Muchas gracias, es mi primera vez aquí, ya lo he cambiado, muy amable

Comment: @Mateo Es una duda de como arreglarlo, o al menos asi lo interpreto, pero bueno, lo se para la proxima. 
Sobre los getters y tal, solo son para probar, acabo de empezar

Comment: No hay de qué @DeepestShadowsDirectosYMas, bienvenido a la comunidad. Cuando pueda respondo a tu duda

Comment: Mira [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/346625/80870) y [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/361399/80870).

Comment: Si bien en Python no existen las [variables privadas](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) como tal, las variables empezadas por 2 guiones bajos son *renombradas* para prevenir colisiones de nombres. Por lo tanto, si quieres acceder a una variable así desde una clase hija, necesitas referirte a ella como `_<class_name>__<atribute_name>`. No lo pongo como respuesta porque puede ser duplicado de [¿Cómo se aplica la encapsulación?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/361399/169744).

Comment: Añadiendo a todo lo anterior, puedes comprobar lo que dice @Mateo haciendo **print(self.__dict__)**: esto te devolverá un diccionario con los nombre y valores de las variables que hayas creado

Comment: Pues lo he solucionado al final.
Gracias @DanielSánchez por el consejo y tu amabilidad, llego a saber eso antes y se me ahorraban unas horitas, y por el código de ejemplo muchas gracias tío.

Comment: Y gracias a @Mateo también ya que no sabía que así se llamaban a las variables.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
def atacar(self, enemigo):
    # le quitamos al enemigo la fuerza del golpe
    enemigo.dano(self.__fuerza)
    # enemigo.__vida -= dano

    print(self.__nombre, "Ha causado", self.__fuerza,
          "puntos de dano a", enemigo.__nombre)
    print("La vida de {a} es actualmente: {b}".format(
        a=enemigo.__nombre, b=enemigo.__vida))

# recibimos la fuerza del golpe
def dano(self, golpe):
    # y se la restamos la fuerza de su vida
    self.__vida -= golpe
```

## nota

recuerda que en programacion no se utilizan tildes, ni caracteres ajenos al ingles como la letra **ñ**